# Multiply scrollbar position when I multiply size of content c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have an image nested inside a panel in my winforms application.

There is a button to zoom in and a button to zoom out.

When the zoom in button is selected, the image doubles in size, and the user can do this twice more if they wanted. Since the size of the image (content) has doubled, the length of the scrollbar also doubles, but stays in the same position. This means that the section of the image the user was previously viewing, is no longer centered.

I would like to find out how I can keep the view position of the content the same as it was before the image is zoomed in / out.

Here's (part of) my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(zoom != 3)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height * 2;
            pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width * 2;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value * 2;
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value * 2;
            zoom = zoom + 1;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (zoom != 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height / 2;
            pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value / 2;
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value / 2;
            zoom = zoom - 1;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I've tried doubling panel1.VerticalScroll.Value and panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value, but this has no effect on the position of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your calculation the size has already changed as have the scroll values.

Simply calculate them **first** and **store** them.

**Then** change the size and **finally** set the new scroll values:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(zoom != 3)
    {
        int scrollV = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value * 2;
        int scrollH = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value * 2;
        pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height * 2;
        pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width * 2;
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollV;
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = scrollH;
        zoom = zoom + 1;
    }
}
```

etc..

Comment: This only seems to be working for the second and third zoom in / out?